# setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled using a style attribute

Tags: android, android-styles

Is it possible when using`AppCompatActivity`to specify `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`using styles, rather than doing so programmatically?

I can specify the drawable itself, but how do I enable it using styles?

```
<style name="MyActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_clear</item>
    <!-- Enable the above using a style attribute -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In styles:

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="displayOptions">showTitle|homeAsUp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

Will launch activity with arrow:

[image]

Comment: I've just tested with an empty project now. It works. Thanks. Not yet sure what was making it not work in the other project.

Comment: I did, but as you pointed out it required a test with an empty project. Just found the issue, and you were declaring `actionBarStyle`, and I was using `actionBarTheme`. I'm not sure why there is two, but specifying the homeAsUpIndicator works in `actionBarTheme` as well as `actionBarStyle`, but `displayOptions` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to enable it via xml. You can only set the parent activity in the manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".CurrentActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivityy" />
    </activity>
```

But you can't enable it via xml. Anyways its just one line of code.

Comment: Declaring parent activity in the AndroidManifest.xml is nothing to do with the question.